# Tooltip removes regression line ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I have the following code in server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

art.data <- read.csv("data1.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({
    col.str <- paste0(input$colspa, ".", input$rgbchoice, ".median")
    p <- ggplot(art.data, aes(x = year, y = art.data[[col.str]], text = paste0(artist, "<br>", art))) + geom_point(size = 1) + xlab("Year") + stat_smooth(method = loess, se = FALSE)
    ggplotly(p , tooltip = "text")
})
})
```

If I remove tooltip then the regression line is there in output graph but with tooltip included, regression line does not appear in the graph. Any solutions to have both the things together?

[With tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGIXo.png)

[Without tooltip in ggplotly() and text in aes()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUXUv.png)

Comment: Please add `data1.csv` or some sample data to get a reproducible example.

Comment: Have you tried plotly package?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I tried but nothing worked. The solution presented below works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aesthetic `text` needs the aesthetic `group`.
Let start considering this example:

```
art.data <- data.frame(year=1430:1490, y=rnorm(61), 
            artist=sample(LETTERS,61, replace=T), art=sample(letters,61, replace=T))
col.str <- 2

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(art.data, aes(x = year, y = art.data[[col.str]], 
                     text=paste0(artist, "<br>", art))) + 
    geom_point(size = 1) + 
    stat_smooth(method = loess, se = FALSE) +
    xlab("Year")
```

In this case the loess line is not plotted on the graph:

[image]

Adding `group=1` in the `ggplot` aesthetics solves the problem:

```
p <- ggplot(art.data, aes(x = year, y = art.data[[col.str]], 
                     text=paste0(artist, "<br>", art), group=1)) + 
    geom_point(size = 1) + 
    stat_smooth(method = loess, se = FALSE) +
    xlab("Year") 
p
```

[image]

and `ggplotly` now works nicely:

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
```

[image]

Comment: That was really helpful! Thank you.